# uitableview to fake a multifont uitextview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

has anyone used a uitableview to write a uitextview-like interface where I would be able to use multiple fonts?

How would I arrange the table and responder?

I need to have a editable view which deals with raw text (the font info would be stored elsewhere). UIWebView doesn't cut it because of both reasons.

Comment: The documentation recommends using a UIWebView to use multi-font text; why do you want to use a UITableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not add a UILabel to a cell in UITableView.  You can use whatever font you want in UILabel.

Also have a hidden UITextView so that you can call first responder on it to bring up the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off just using `UIWebView` for this.

Comment: Clarified the question: UIWebView is not editable and full of html gunk.

Comment: Can't JavaScript be used to edit the DOM? Not sure what's gunk in HTML but building the equivalent of a word processor from `UITextField` elements is going to be a fair amount of work.